# Tomcat Domain Redirection For Particular Resource Path

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, redirect

Is it possible to redirect a particular resource path to a different domain in tomcat .Eg : http://localhost:8080/web/redirectpath to http://192.168.1.1:8080/anotherwar/redirectpath. (web(war) resides in my tomcat and 192.168.1.1 is a remote server)

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways.

For example you can do it in code in your servlet, if you have a servlet:
`HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect(url)`

The same code you can use in Filter. This way you don't need a servlet, you only need to register your Filter in the web.xml

You can decide in code if it should redirect, let's say based on the url.
Alternately, you can put only the matching url mapping in the web.xml